# Generate certain list from two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists.

```
l1={
    {"Mn", "Mn1", 1., "B", 1.4}, 
    {"Al", "Al1", 1., "B", 1.4}
   };

l2={
   {{1, 1, 0.}, {11, 11, 0.}},

   {{2, 2, 0.}, {22, 22, 0.}, {222, 222, 0.}}
   }
```

This is a short version of the lists. The two lists always have the same `Length` so that their level-1 elements have a one-to-one relation. However, the elements of `l2` can have varying `Length` as shown here.

I'd like to generate a new list as follows.

```
l3=
{
    {"Mn", "Mn1", {1, 1, 0.}, 1., "B", 1.4},
    {"Mn", "Mn1", {11, 11, 0.}, 1., "B", 1.4},

    {"Al", "Al1", {2, 2, 0.}, 1., "B", 1.4},
    {"Al", "Al1", {22, 22, 0.}, 1., "B", 1.4},
    {"Al", "Al1", {222, 222, 0.}, 1., "B", 1.4}
}
```

I think `MapThread` might be the direction to go, but I cannot think of any function to obtain the result. I'm not stick to `MapThread`. Any function that can do the job is okay as long as it's a vertorization method since that's what MMA favors.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate your receipt for l3 in detail? I understand nothing. BTW, the notation "l" is not good: compare with "I" and "1".

Comment: @user64494, it's really difficult for me to think of a good way to describe the format of `l3` for English isn't my first language. That's why I use newlines to separate elements of `l1` and `l2` and change values of `l2` to `1,11` and `2, 22, 222` for clarity. Maybe you could help me with that. But I think the answers provided understood my need and returns the desired format of `l3`. Also, I appreciate the suggestions of `l1/2/3` may not be a good variable name. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use `MapThread`:

```
l3 = Join @@ MapThread[Function[{x, y}, Insert[x, #, 3] & /@ y], {l1, l2}]
```

Here's a more esoteric version that builds lists of mapping operators from `l2` and then applies them to the elements of `l1`:

```
l3 = Join @@ MapThread[Through[#1[#2]] &, {Map[Insert[#, 3] &, l2, {2}], l1}]
```

[See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200053/26598) for a discussion of the `Through[#1[#2]]&` operator.

Comment: A good code is a commented code. Comments are useful to both readers and authors.

Comment: @user64494 I expect some effort from the reader: the analysis and exegesis of other people's code snippets is a great learning tool. _Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime._

Comment: @Roman, I like the 1st solution you provided because that's what I can remember in brain once I learn it. I was struggling with `Part`, but yours enlightened me. I'll need to understand better the `Through` approach. First time I heard of this function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also `MapThread` the function `Thread[Insert[#, #2, 3]] &` on the pair of lists `{l1,l2}`:

```
Join @@ MapThread[Thread[Insert[#, #2, 3]] &, {l1, l2}]
```

> {{Mn, Mn1, {1, 1, 0.}, 1., B, 1.4}, {Mn, Mn1, {11, 11, 0.}, 1., B, 1.4},
>   {Al, Al1, {2, 2, 0.}, 1., B, 1.4}, {Al, Al1, {22, 22, 0.}, 1., B, 1.4}, {Al, Al1, {222, 222, 0.}, 1., B, 1.4}}

Alternatively, use the `MapThread/Thread` combination to create pairings appended with `3` and apply `Insert` to the resulting triples:

```
Join @@ Apply[Insert, 
  MapThread[Thread[{##, 3}, List, {2}] &, {l1, l2}], 
 {2}]
```

> same result

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for! Thanks. Prefix it with `Join@@` to match the spec.

Comment: @kglr, I never think of using `Thread` function before reading your answer. It's a little bit difficult for me to appreciate the mechanism of `Thread`. It's written _"threads" f over any lists that appear in args_ in MMA's help page. But elements of `l1` and `l2` are both lists. I think `Insert` plays a role here so that the `function` only threads over `element of l2`. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks

Comment: @Yaofeng, you are right for the first one. In the second, the second and third arguments of `Thread` controls what to thread over and in which positions.

Comment: @kglr, I compared the `AbsoluteTiming` for your `Thread` solution and Roman's `Function` solution. Yours is faster. Although it's not intuitive for me at the moment, but I guess that's the direction for me to go, in line with MMA's vectorization. Thanks again!

Comment: Although I think your `Thread[Insert[##,3]]` method is the most poetic, it's also the most brittle: `Insert`ing first and `Thread`ing second makes the assumption that none of the elements of the lists in `l1` are themselves lists. Example: with `l1 = {{"Mn", {"Mn1"}, 1., "B", 1.4}, {"Al", "Al1", 1., "B", 1.4}}` this method throws a `Thread::tdlen`. To be more robust it's probably advisable to `Thread` first and `Insert` second, as in your second method.

Comment: @Roman very good point.