# Best way to apply a list of functions to a list of values?

Tags: functional-style, operators, code-golf

This question is closely related to questions [83720](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83720/26598), [17460](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17460/26598), and [11298](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/26598).

How would you write the operator

```
F = Through[#1[#2]] &
```

in the prettiest, fastest, or most poetic way? It just looks clumsy the way I've written it.

Also, can you think of any pitfalls? Edge cases where this function does not behave regularly?

What `F` does is to apply a list of functions to a list of values:

```
F[{Sin, Cos, Tan}, {x, y}]
(*    {{Sin[x], Sin[y]}, {Cos[x], Cos[y]}, {Tan[x], Tan[y]}}    *)
```

#### benchmarks of solutions

Here's a benchmark of all solutions, sorted from fastest to slowest.

```
(* random functions and random data *)
a = Table[Function[x, Evaluate[x + RandomReal[]]], {10^4}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^4];
```

original post: very fast

```
F = Through[#1[#2]] &;
c0 = F[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    0.506063    *)
```

contracted syntax: a little bit slower

```
F = Through@*Construct;
c1 = F[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    0.85128    *)
```

[dataset query](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107811/26598): still a bit slower

```
F = Query[#1][#2] &;
c2 = F[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    1.45958    *)
```

explicit outer-product construction: terribly slow

```
F = Outer[Construct, ##] &;
c3 = F[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    83.0245    *)
```

check that all solutions agree on the result:

```
c0 == c1 == c2 == c3
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: There is one pitfall you have to be aware of, which is that you're relying on your functions to be `Listable` in the examples you're giving (`Cos`, `Sin` and `Tan`). For a list of non-listable functions you'd need `F = Through[(Map /@ #1)[#2]] &`.

Comment: Thanks @SjoerdSmit! Yes that's a very important one.

Answer (score 6):

To streamline the syntax of `F = Through[#1[#2]]&` we can do

```
F = Through@*Construct
```

Alternatively, an explicit outer product:

```
F = Outer[Construct, ##] &
```

Comment: What is the purpose or function of `*` here?

Comment: @CATrevillian [operator composition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

Comment: sweet!! That’s awesome as all get-out! Many thanks. Side note: does any resource exist of just these shorthand inputs? They’re my favourites

Comment: @CATrevillian Here's the list of all [operator input forms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) sorted by precedence.

Comment: +1, ro-man, +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Comap`:** (since v14.0, 2023)

```
Comap[{Sin, Cos, Tan}, {x, y}]
```

---

> {{Sin[x],Sin[y]},{Cos[x],Cos[y]},{Tan[x],Tan[y]}}

Comment: Thanks. Is it competitive performance-wise?

Comment: The `Comap` is slower by a factor of `15.5` compare to `F = Through@*Construct`. @chris